# In nodejs, when use json.stringify() -> error

Tags: json, node.js

I've json object ( this json object returned from database):

> { created_at: 'Wed Nov 21 19:28:24 +0000 2012',
>     id: 271334264140869630,
>     id_str: '271334264140869633',
>   }{ created_at: 'Wed Nov 21 19:28:24 +0000 2012',
>     id: 271334264140869630,
>     id_str: '271334264140869633',
>   }

When I've use JSON.stringify(obj) ->

> { "created_at": "Wed Nov 21 19:28:24 +0000 2012",
>     "id": "271334264140869630",
>     "id_str": "271334264140869633"
>   }{ "created_at": "Wed Nov 21 19:28:24 +0000 2012",
>     "id": "271334264140869630",
>     "id_str": "271334264140869633"
>   }

This obj invalid on http://jsonlint.com/, because error:**Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'**

Pls help me fix this error.

Comment: The javascript object returned from the database is not valid either in what you posted.

Comment: Are you stringifying and printing in a loop? Please show some of the code that generates all this.

Answer (score 1):

Below is your valid JSON.

```
[
    {
        "created_at": "WedNov2119: 28: 24+00002012",
        "id": 271334264140869630,
        "id_str": "271334264140869633"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "WedNov2119: 28: 24+00002012",
        "id": 271334264140869630,
        "id_str": "271334264140869633"
    }
]
```

1. If multiple objects are present in parent Object, it forms an array
   and should be separated by comma ",". The array should be wrapped with squre brackets "[]"
2. The Id of an object must be string, for being validated by jsonlint. If value is string, quote it with double quotes "".

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/89Zvw/) to test stringify operation